# how to nest a column into itself in tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
```

why does this produce a list column 'am':

```
mtcars %>%
group_by(cyl) %>%
mutate(am=list(mtcars[,'am']))
```

but not:

```
mtcars %>%
group_by(cyl) %>%
nest() %>%
mutate(am=list(mtcars[,'am']))
```

Error: not compatible with STRSXP

I realize this is a bit of a contrived example, but it's relevant to what I'm working on. Does mutate not scope outside its environment?

Comment: Look at what you're passing after you `nest()`; the resulting data.frame only has 3 rows. There's no obvious way to add the new data; it's not grouped because you're not calling it from an existing column, but bringing it in from outside the chain with the new reference to `mtcars`. A way to grab the existing `am` column already nested in `data` would be `mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    nest() %>% mutate(am = map(data, 'am'))`. To bring it in from outside, split it to fit the groups: `mutate(am = split(mtcars$am, mtcars$cyl))`

Comment: I am trying to bring in all the data from mtcars. I literally want the entire original column "am" from mtcars repeated for each group in a list column. Calling mtcars as I did,  mtcars should be unmodified and I should just be able to store the whole dataframe as a list element of the new "am" column. neither of your proposals do that.

Comment: `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest() %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(am = list(mtcars$am))` or `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest() %>% mutate(am = rep(list(mtcars$am), n()))`, though it seems pretty pointless...

Comment: Thanks! works as expected...even though I still don't get why mine shouldn't work. post as a solution and i'll accept.

Comment: since you're likely wondering, i have some complicated functions to produce other list columns and I realized I excluded an important output. the functions are used in a couple different scripts so I don't want to change them. this will let me add the column back into the list columns created by those functions. not ideal, but it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest()

## # A tibble: 3 × 2
##     cyl               data
##   <dbl>             <list>
## 1     6  <tibble [7 × 10]>
## 2     4 <tibble [11 × 10]>
## 3     8 <tibble [14 × 10]>
```

has three rows, so any column you need has to have three elements, as well.

If you want the full `am` column for each row, you can either mutate rowwise, which will evaluate the `mutate` call separately for each row,

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest() %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(am = list(mtcars$am))

## Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
## Groups: <by row>
## 
## # A tibble: 3 × 3
##     cyl               data         am
##   <dbl>             <list>     <list>
## 1     6  <tibble [7 × 10]> <dbl [32]>
## 2     4 <tibble [11 × 10]> <dbl [32]>
## 3     8 <tibble [14 × 10]> <dbl [32]>
```

or without `rowwise`, just repeat the desired list for each row:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest() %>% mutate(am = rep(list(mtcars$am), n()))

## # A tibble: 3 × 3
##     cyl               data         am
##   <dbl>             <list>     <list>
## 1     6  <tibble [7 × 10]> <dbl [32]>
## 2     4 <tibble [11 × 10]> <dbl [32]>
## 3     8 <tibble [14 × 10]> <dbl [32]>
```